# Problem of selector access with the JsonPropertyAccessor

Tags: json, spring-integration, spring-el

I encouter a problem while accessing a JsonNode with org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser into a Spring Boot 2.2.4 service.
I can describe the issue with the example below:

Given the Json as root object in a StandardEvaluationContext :

`{"property":[{"name":"value1"},{"name":"value2"}]}`

the spring expression language value with selector below returns `value1` with no problem:

`property.^[name != null].name`

but this selector below returns `null` instead of `value1`:

`property.^[name == 'value1'].name`

any idea ?

EDIT:

here's a main method class example:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.json.JsonPropertyAccessor;

public class TestJsonAccessor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        context.setPropertyAccessors(List.of(new JsonPropertyAccessor()));
        context.setRootObject(new ObjectMapper().readTree("{\"property\":[{\"name\":\"value1\"},{\"name\":\"value2\"}]}"));

        SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

        System.out.println(parser.parseExpression("property.^[name != null].name").getValue(context));
        System.out.println(parser.parseExpression("property.^[name == 'value1'].name").getValue(context));
    }
}
```

in the console that prints :

```
value1
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:272)
    at TestJsonAccessor.main(TestJsonAccessor.java:20)
```

Comment: show, please, how you use it

Comment: I added an example in ogiginal post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here: `name == 'value1'`. That `name` is not a plain text to compare - it is a `ToStringFriendlyJsonNode` and to make it working expected with that `equal` operator you need to make it as string. Therefore like this:

```
property.^[name.toString() == 'value1'].name
```

There is another much longer way to reach the goal:

```
property.^[name.getTarget().asText() == 'value1'].name
```

The point of the `JsonPropertyAccessor` it to make a final result end-user friendly. In the middle it is still some JSON object we need to deal with.

Comment: Ah ok I see now, thank you. But I find it breaks a bit with usual selector dsl. If we compare with json-path, for instance.
Though it is not, why don't we think about an adaptator more javabean friendly?

Comment: Actually, I also find this ToStringFriendlyJsonNode a little bit confusing. Why don't we return directly the JsonNode object ?

Comment: I think I can suggest via a PR a more javabean friendly approach for the selector. I guess this is done via the equals method of ToStringFriendlyJsonNode, and a manner to avoid render back the ToStringFriendlyJsonNode actually...

Comment: See PR on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3270